# Battery drain after switching drive to a different laptop

Tags: drivers, windows-11, battery, battery-life

After switching my NVMe SSD over from my Dell Latitude 7300 over to my Dell Latitude 5300 (very similar hardware and specs, both Windows 11), the battery life has considerably decreased (10 hours to about 5 hours). Both laptops have brand new batteries. How can I rectify this without having to perform a clean reinstall, etc? Is it a driver issue or something?

Comment: What was the drive you switched back (2 laptops 2 drives). Was it a HDD that takes more power?

Comment: No, I just swapped the SSDs of both laptops

Comment: That clarifies.  If the SSD has incorrect or somewhat incompatible power drivers and potentially BIOS (UEFI) that could cause your issue. I do think you might be looking at a fresh install to fix the differences.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by incompatible BIOS

Comment: Different models may have different BIOS levels. Your models are not the same so BIOS is most likely different.